# join two lists in java without null

Tags: java, arrays, list

i have two lists they are of type car .

car class has 4 strings variable :

```
    color;
 model;
```

//for second

```
color;
model;
```

now i want to join these two lists with out any null cuz first list has :

```
color="red";
model=null;
```

second list ;

```
color=null
model="2010"
```

so I want them like:

```
color="red";
model="2010"
```

without null

Comment: Where are these lists and why do you say 4 string variables? That looks like 2 per `Car`.

Comment: So it seems like there are just two `Car` objects with 2 strings in there. Where are the lists?

Comment: list say it called List<Car> cars1;  and List<Car> cars2;

Comment: Why not construct the code so you don't have those `null`s in the first place?

Comment: cuz i read it from database and don't know where is the null

Comment: You have to give more information about the lists and the expected results. ie, What happens when one list is longer than the other, what happens if one car has null for both values, what if both lists have a model but not a color, etc.

Comment: that is my Q  clcto , in two lists in don't know how much it size and what is actual variables , i'm just want to add one with second but ignore any null value

Comment: look it this : http://www.screencast.com/t/G05qB8qAKp , first two column represent first list , and the last two columns represent list2 so each of lists has different size and values

Comment: Why dont you use a `Map<String,Car>`?

Comment: If you don't know how the data is structured and what the result should be, how should anyone else be able to tell?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to create a `List<Car>` that gets the color from one list and the model from the other. To do this, just create new `Car`s and add them to a new `List`:

```
List<Car> newlist = new ArrayList<Car>();
for( int i = 0; i < list1.size() && i < list2.size(); ++i )
    newlist.Add( new Car( list1.get(i).getColor(), list2.get(i).getModel() ) );
```

However if you do not know which list contains `null` for each car, you would have to do some checks:

```
for( int i = 0; i < list1.size() && i < list2.size(); ++i )
{
    String color = list1.get(i).getColor();
    if( color == null )
        color = list2.get(i).getColor();

    String model = list1.get(i).getModel();
    if( model == null )
        model = list2.get(i).getModel();

    newlist.Add( new Car( color, model ) );
}
```

Note: I assumed `Car` has a common interface, ie:

```
class Car
{
    public String getModel(){ return model; }
    public String getColor(){ return color; }
    public Car( String c, String m )
    {
        color = c;
        model = m;
    }
}
```

Comment: note that size of list1 not equal list2 so it will get out of index

Comment: It won't get out of index, it just won't look at all of them.

Comment: if size of list1 is 5 and size of list2 10 then the code will out in i=4